# What's the max possible length of an id list that can be sent to YT video API?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I call YT.Channel API with a list of Ids and I get an error:

```
GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to youtube.channels.list failed with error: Request contains an invalid argument.


YouTube.Channels.list('id, snippet, statistics', {
      id: resultsParentChannelIdsPerPage.join()
    }).getItems()

id =  UC5JU3rLOMvB7ZIXI2oi1ubg,UC4mKtxAtWQgmkFC6S6siNVg,UC-4hR9ralZoAW15tAwSbJ_A,UCvdwiASqQrIIozQcVAXvRXw,UCUIKx2bIjRcBWyIa3AQGSCg,UClkJAMCknefAzrYfpk1_0Nw,UCsDm3gAWuDRDLMjZLoUxOuA,UC-OkSUXpLrS2eBpztAJ78wg,UCb6RivygioXGs0icq4McBdg,UCmAf6BdYS-5QmXxBuJZgNpQ,UC6rDrJjome8e_iBQI1MLeZg,UCJ0lYZCucWTPc_IfE2vZNTg,UCVy5saLw3psF5laPWhahGHA,UCXskq-my9ltmT6SpdL7b_cw,UCpctmQs9AEwiIZgTcWSV0mg,UCv4ZlVO5-z-uVIm1Y6ol-DA,UCPtQnd-8OBSzvqnQVKaA_8g,UC_uQYR3lHS36jkBRqdvQIFw,UCoJuf64ajKTOZ6mX30zulKg,UCM-GJfgjXFajHll_uGeZPBQ,UC2ojGYd_fg8oU71beXUMW9g,UCT_dVMJ2eSGKugeXnMZcbfQ,UC6PHRps6wOfBJKoDxEI37Ew,UC2Ra3RK4FW38skAoYEtXJbQ,UC2u7_TuItL4on_9SuwJhO_A,UCt-gKqNg_k2bb-bSe7y3z4g,UC2UotqDGeOMUl-gQG3t9sKw,UCdbVBcrKBtu8oUcp4JuLpvw,UCKHpDyswx5VskURci4FPqUA,UCiNHdTU2jYRbUf1cbMCxdaQ,UC3osMa_MdseDVrXlbZFSZDw,UCbnwaC-Tbi1duuDbjfV-Thg,UCBOrTOryVc2JKsNOu7_wO6g,UCM8UoJ4z4NMvp5pwYQjx8uQ,UCnU2sysDk58MuMQHxqgDd7w,UCuldUFBFddgeVN6HJ-yIBjA,UCsEgNI5S2Vdy3Q7LizK2OSA,UClN9w3sTTs6lpntoeHyYvSA,UCgZlOI3AqanZW0tjCSJCKfA,UCqS9WhAUJ-6PiC-8mZ0rDSQ,UCBH5Es0HeCBBlHvWG9c2ipA,UCpPgyVE8TKJr-MnpB44Au4w,UCJxgQl6TU8FGmMzG24xxYFg,UCpe9hHSEkTs5BD6Ufi0-XuA,UCrk1G4da0dsnLsPjsov5fTA,UCtF629dMzswzAupMUEO-bPw,UCsRcjJkUmU_Ny5D9pn5ZGDw,UC5Wm0eXXRAA6Pcjlq8-EaLw,UCOakkksW_nWRDkPl43VzAQA,UC4JhVBsy-Yfr3dQy7G1EYuQ,UCfS8vOYmleKZU8zNjzsZ6qg,UCPWsJzhhZSPlfQ7DOjSA4Fg,UCPKKa8RgdfoMRBkyt8BhIqA,UCa3bfoq50eqErBDgq0p2cQA,UCyH05wKVW-96Lz2mqhGnzVw,UCiXjl5HwqmuCjr5ZmW00csQ,UCA9tlIHeg-k8z3PUpozkUmA,UC_Bc8M2p5fpYqlfWvbVmw2g,UCnD86huZnRWKDMZISbQx6kg,UCtRn5U4Uz2vbREF0qD0TLuA
```

I didn't get this in previous similar runs. What has changed?

[API explorer](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list?apix_params=%7B%22id%22%3A%5B%22%20UC5JU3rLOMvB7ZIXI2oi1ubg%2CUC4mKtxAtWQgmkFC6S6siNVg%2CUC-4hR9ralZoAW15tAwSbJ_A%2CUCvdwiASqQrIIozQcVAXvRXw%2CUCUIKx2bIjRcBWyIa3AQGSCg%2CUClkJAMCknefAzrYfpk1_0Nw%2CUCsDm3gAWuDRDLMjZLoUxOuA%2CUC-OkSUXpLrS2eBpztAJ78wg%2CUCb6RivygioXGs0icq4McBdg%2CUCmAf6BdYS-5QmXxBuJZgNpQ%2CUC6rDrJjome8e_iBQI1MLeZg%2CUCJ0lYZCucWTPc_IfE2vZNTg%2CUCVy5saLw3psF5laPWhahGHA%2CUCXskq-my9ltmT6SpdL7b_cw%2CUCpctmQs9AEwiIZgTcWSV0mg%2CUCv4ZlVO5-z-uVIm1Y6ol-DA%2CUCPtQnd-8OBSzvqnQVKaA_8g%2CUC_uQYR3lHS36jkBRqdvQIFw%2CUCoJuf64ajKTOZ6mX30zulKg%2CUCM-GJfgjXFajHll_uGeZPBQ%2CUC2ojGYd_fg8oU71beXUMW9g%2CUCT_dVMJ2eSGKugeXnMZcbfQ%2CUC6PHRps6wOfBJKoDxEI37Ew%2CUC2Ra3RK4FW38skAoYEtXJbQ%2CUC2u7_TuItL4on_9SuwJhO_A%2CUCt-gKqNg_k2bb-bSe7y3z4g%2CUC2UotqDGeOMUl-gQG3t9sKw%2CUCdbVBcrKBtu8oUcp4JuLpvw%2CUCKHpDyswx5VskURci4FPqUA%2CUCiNHdTU2jYRbUf1cbMCxdaQ%2CUC3osMa_MdseDVrXlbZFSZDw%2CUCbnwaC-Tbi1duuDbjfV-Thg%2CUCBOrTOryVc2JKsNOu7_wO6g%2CUCM8UoJ4z4NMvp5pwYQjx8uQ%2CUCnU2sysDk58MuMQHxqgDd7w%2CUCuldUFBFddgeVN6HJ-yIBjA%2CUCsEgNI5S2Vdy3Q7LizK2OSA%2CUClN9w3sTTs6lpntoeHyYvSA%2CUCgZlOI3AqanZW0tjCSJCKfA%2CUCqS9WhAUJ-6PiC-8mZ0rDSQ%2CUCBH5Es0HeCBBlHvWG9c2ipA%2CUCpPgyVE8TKJr-MnpB44Au4w%2CUCJxgQl6TU8FGmMzG24xxYFg%2CUCpe9hHSEkTs5BD6Ufi0-XuA%2CUCrk1G4da0dsnLsPjsov5fTA%2CUCtF629dMzswzAupMUEO-bPw%2CUCsRcjJkUmU_Ny5D9pn5ZGDw%2CUC5Wm0eXXRAA6Pcjlq8-EaLw%2CUCOakkksW_nWRDkPl43VzAQA%2CUC4JhVBsy-Yfr3dQy7G1EYuQ%2CUCfS8vOYmleKZU8zNjzsZ6qg%2CUCPWsJzhhZSPlfQ7DOjSA4Fg%2CUCPKKa8RgdfoMRBkyt8BhIqA%2CUCa3bfoq50eqErBDgq0p2cQA%2CUCyH05wKVW-96Lz2mqhGnzVw%2CUCiXjl5HwqmuCjr5ZmW00csQ%2CUCA9tlIHeg-k8z3PUpozkUmA%2CUC_Bc8M2p5fpYqlfWvbVmw2g%2CUCnD86huZnRWKDMZISbQx6kg%2CUCtRn5U4Uz2vbREF0qD0TLuA%22%5D%7D)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing has changed, as far as I know. Fact is that -- with the exception of [`CommentThreads.list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/commentThreads/list), [`Comments.list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/comments/list) and [`Members.list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/members/list) endpoints -- all YouTube Data API endpoints that are providing result sets would not return result sets of more than 50 items.

Therefore, when using the [`Channels.list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list) endpoint's request parameter [`id`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list#id), you'll have to limit yourself to pass to it a comma-separated list of channel IDs of *at most 50 elements*.